# Pandas groupby size "count" intermittent under-count

Tags: pandas

Why am I getting inconsistent group size "counts"?
I am using Pandas 10.0, with a 6 million row dataset being reduced to a 400k groupby:

```
In [16]: df.groupby('Z ID').size()[470009:470010]
Out[16]:
Z ID
994555          6

In [14]: df[df['Z ID'] == 994555].groupby('Z ID').size() 
Out[14]:
Z ID
994555          9
```

*When I reviewed the raw data there are 9 items.*

**EDIT: Raw Data**
The full data set is 6 million records.  Pandas size() works great on the little guy.

```
            FilterDate           Z ID   AR Code AA Code
48349    12/1/2007..2/28/2009    994555  377     202
151060   2/1/2008..4/30/2009     994555  377     202
204179   3/1/2008..5/31/2009     994555  377     202
244504   4/1/2008..6/30/2009     994555  377     202
302728   5/1/2008..7/31/2009     994555  377     202
365780   6/1/2008..8/31/2009     994555  377     202
431555   7/1/2008..9/30/2009     994555  377     202
499234   8/1/2008..10/31/2009    994555  377     202
786937   12/1/2008..2/28/2010    994555  377     202
```

Comment: Can you try to find a minimal example and/or dump a (possibly censored) version of the dataset somewhere?

Comment: Is this "intermittent" or does it always differs on these two ways of calling?

Comment: So out of 400k results I find near the end issues of miscounting.  It does do most of them right.  I haven't found a sure fire way yet to count to quantify how many are being miss-counted.

Comment: I reduced to a series and did a value_counts it worked like a charm.  The only thing I could figure out that might be the issue is in the dataframe dtypes were all object (vs int64) but once I drop to the series, it went to longs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that the dtypes were 'object', I wonder if your Z_ID is being loaded as a column of strings, causing a factor column.  If some of the strings have leading spaces, they would be interpreted as a different factor level.

More generally, whatever 'object' type the column holds might have a comparison function that doesn't work the way you think it does.  This is a bit of a stretch.

The better thing for you might be to figure out why your dataframe column dtype was not int64.  I've found that getting the dtypes correct in the dataframe is very important when working in pandas.  If you can post a bit of code, I'm confident the community here can give a suggestion to load the types properly.